# Including interface implementation inside interface right approach?

Tags: java, performance, interface, tree, binary-heap

While browsing the code of a project, I encountered an implementation of `BinaryHeap` where two implementations (using Array and Tree) were packed inside the interface itself. I found it somewhat complicated. The code is:

```
public interface BinaryHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> extends IHeap<T>  {
   //some variables and other declarations.

   public static class BinaryHeapArray<T extends Comparable<T>> implements BinaryHeap<T> { 
     //Implementation based on Array
   }

   public static class BinaryHeapTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements BinaryHeap<T> {
     //Implementation based on Tree
   }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach? How can it be improved in terms of readability?

Comment: The classes could be made top level classes. I am not keen on nesting lengthy public classes in general.

Comment: This sort of structure could be useful for school settings. If the teacher tells all the students to implement their assignment using this interface, it makes it easier for her to automatically test them. It seems less useful for production purposes.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the rest of that interface.

Comment: @RealSkeptic :D but I have seen it in a real life project. And I feel such code is nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong, per se (i.e., the library does compile :-)), but it's definitely awkward. At the very least, it forces you to always import both implementations every time you want to use the interface.

I'd have the interface as a standalone interface, and declare to other top-level classes for the implementations.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Mureinik, the readability of code can be improved by having,

1. A standalone interface
2. Have those classes inside a interface as top-level classes.

The idea of having those classes inside an interface can be for following reasons:
a. **Binding** BinaryHeapArray and BinaryHeapTree classes **Strongly** to BinaryHeap.
b. One more reason could be to have modifiable data within an interface(As you may know all fields in an interface are implicitly final). By declaring a class inside the interface you can have common MODIFIABLE data.